# Realizar dois COUNT com INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Ao utilizar a `SQL` abaixo para realizar a contagem do número de corretores em uma tabela utilizando `INNER JOIN`, funciona perfeitamente.

SQL:

```
SELECT
    conta.acesso,
    count(corretor.cod) as num_corr
    FROM
    conta
    INNER JOIN corretor
    ON conta.id = corretor.cod
    where conta.id = '1015'
```

Porém, ao tentar incluir a contagem também do número de usuário, aí tudo para de funcionar. Veja a `SQL` abaixo:

```
SELECT
    conta.acesso,
    count(corretor.cod) as num_corr,
    count(usuarios.cliente) as num_user
    FROM
    conta
    INNER JOIN corretor
    ON conta.id = corretor.cod
    INNER JOIN usuarios
    ON conta.id = usuarios.cliente
    where conta.id = '1015'
```

Nesta `SQL` apenas incluí para contar a tabela usuários e nada mais funciona.

Comment: De certeza que 'ON conta.id = usuarios.cliente' dá certo? Tenta sem o count primeiro; ou seja, SELECT
    conta.acesso,
    count(corretor.cod) as num_corr,
    usuarios.cliente as num_user
    FROM...

Comment: @White Sim fiz este teste antes e funciona, só no inner que não

Comment: Queres experimentar com 'left join' ? Estou só a dar ideias...

Comment: @White como faço?

Comment: usar o group by?

Comment: Qual o seu banco? E o seu primeiro SQL realmente funciona sem o `Group by`?

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro Meu banco é MYSQL e funciona sem o GROUP BY

Comment: É só substituir, INNER JOIN por LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente essas duas formas, talvez te ajude ou de uma luz:

```
SELECT co.acesso
      ,c.num_corr
      ,u.num_user
  FROM conta co
 LEFT JOIN (select cod, count(cod) as num_corr from corretor)         c ON co.id = c.cod
 LEFT JOIN (select cliente, count(cliente) as num_user from usuarios) u ON co.id = u.cliente
 WHERE co.id = '1015'
```

OU

```
SELECT co.acesso
      ,count(c.cod)     as num_corr
      ,count(u.cliente) as num_user
  FROM conta co
 LEFT JOIN corretor c ON c.cod     = co.id
 LEFT JOIN usuarios u ON u.cliente = co.id 
 WHERE co.id = '1015'
 GROUP BY co.acesso
```

**EDITADO**

```
SELECT co.acesso
      ,c.num_corr
      ,u.num_user
  FROM conta co
 LEFT JOIN (select cod, count(cod) as num_corr from corretor group by cod)             c ON co.id = c.cod
 LEFT JOIN (select cliente, count(cliente) as num_user from usuarios group by cliente) u ON co.id = u.cliente
 WHERE co.id = '1015'
 GROUP BY co.acesso
```

Comment: Deu certo em parte, pois o resultado para a soma dos dois join estão sendo iguais. Vou tentar explicar o que está acontecendo. os valores estão se repetindo para os resultados dos joins.

Comment: Tanto corretor quanto usuários estão exibindo valores 6. Quanto na verdade tem no banco de dados para corretor 2 e usuário 3

Comment: As duas formas que te indiquei deram o mesmo resultado?

Comment: Não, o primeiro dobrou o valor. O segundo exibiu para corretor quanto para usuário o valor 6.

Comment: Qual será o problema destes resultados errados?

Comment: Verifique a edição da minha resposta, fiz um exemplo aqui parecido com o seu e funcionou.